# Ограничение области прокрутки в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть таблица с большим количеством столбцов, как создать фиксированную область (например 5 первых столбцов), которая не должна прокручиваться(ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНО!) в отличие от всех остальных столбцов в этой таблице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `position: sticky`
https://codepen.io/Vicetjs/pen/VpQPeR

Comment: Спасибо! Вполне устраивает.